# C++ dynamic type construction and detection

Tags: c++, runtime, mixins

There was an interesting problem in C++, but it was more about architecture.

There are many (10, 20, 40, etc) classes describing some characteristics (mix-in classes), for example:

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base() {} };

struct A : virtual public Base { int size; };
struct B : virtual public Base { float x, y; };
struct C : virtual public Base { bool some_bool_state; };
struct D : virtual public Base { string str; }
// ....
```

The primary module declares and exports a function (for simplicity just function declarations without classes):

```
// .h file
void operate(Base *pBase);

// .cpp file
void operate(Base *pBase)
{
    // ....
}
```

Any other module can have code like this:

```
#include "mixing.h"
#include "primary.h"

class obj1_t : public A, public C, public D {};
class obj2_t : public B, public D {};

// ...
void Pass()
{
    obj1_t obj1;
    obj2_t obj2;

    operate(&obj1);
    operate(&obj2);
}
```

The question is how do you know what the real type of a given object in `operate()` is without using `dynamic_cast` and any type information in classes (constants, etc)? The `operate()` function is used with a big array of objects in small time periods and `dynamic_cast` is too slow for it and I don't want to include constants (`enum obj_type { ... }`) because this is not the OOP-way.

```
// module operate.cpp

void some_operate(Base *pBase)
{
    processA(pBase);
    processB(pBase);
}

void processA(A *pA)
{
}

void processB(B *pB)
{
}
```

I cannot directly pass a `pBase` to these functions. And it's impossible to have all possible combinations of classes, because I can add new classes just by including new header files.

One solution that came to mind, in the editor I can use a composite container:

```
struct CompositeObject
{
    vector<Base *pBase> parts;
};
```

But the editor does not need time optimization and can use `dynamic_cast` for parts to determine the exact type. In `operate()` I cannot use this solution.

So, is it possible to avoid using a `dynamic_cast` and type information to solve this problem? Or maybe I should use another architecture?

Comment: why do you need to know the real type? Why can't you use virtual functions?

Comment: You have restricted on all possible ways dynamic_cast,RTTI, using constants  or Storing "string typeName" , you left one option "another architecture" that is what Neil answered.

Comment: > Why can't you use virtual functions? 
because there are no common interface for these mixin classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem here is about what you are trying to achieve.

Do you want something like:

```
void operate(A-B& ) { operateA(); operateB(); }

// OR

void operate(A-B& ) { operateAB(); }
```

That is, do you want to apply an operation on each subcomponent (independently), or do you wish to be able to apply operations depending on the combination of components (much harder).

I'll take the first approach here.

**1. Virtual ?**

```
class Base { public: virtual void operate() = 0; };

class A: virtual public Base { public virtual void operate() = 0; };
void A::operate() { ++size; } // yes, it's possible to define a pure virtual

class obj1_t: public A, public B
{
public:
  virtual void operate() { A::operate(); B::operate(); }
};
```

Some more work, for sure. Notably I don't like the repetition much. But that's one call to the _vtable, so it should be one of the fastest solution!

**2. Composite Pattern**

That would probably be the more natural thing here.

Note that you can perfectly use a template version of the pattern in C++!

```
template <class T1, class T2, class T3>
class BaseT: public Base, private T1, private T2, private T3
{
public:
  void operate() { T1::operate(); T2::operate(); T3::operate(); }
};

class obj1_t: public BaseT<A,B,C> {};
```

Advantages:

- no more need to repeat yourself! write `operate` once and for all (baring variadic...)
- only 1 virtual call, no more virtual inheritance, so even more efficient that before
- `A`, `B` and `C` can be of arbitrary type, they should not inherit from `Base` at all
- **edit** the `operate` method of `A`, `B` and `C` may be inlined now that it's not `virtual`

Disadvantage:

Some more work on the framework if you don't have access to variadic templates yet, but it's feasible within a couple dozen of lines.

Comment: +1, and you can take a look at boost::preprocessor to avoid writing much of the boilerplate if you do not have a variadic template implementation.

Comment: I was going to write it down, but then GMan will pop around and qualify me of preprocessor madman :p

Comment: Thanks for response, but I wrote that mix-in classes have not any common interface. And I know about Composite but cannot use it because final type can derive from any number of mixin classes. I just want to have a way to use a composite object as a simple.

struct TransA
{
    void operator()(A *pa) { pa->size -= 10; }
};

void Update(B *pb, Point2 p) { // ... }
void Cap(D *pd) { // ... }

void f(vector<Base *> o)
{
for_each(o.begin(), o.end(), TransA());
Cap(*o.begin());
};

I can use Visitor pattern, but for now I have more than 20 classes and number of functions is too big.

Comment: Then you're screwed. They **need** to have a common interface (at the very least an `accept` method for the `Visitor` pattern). As for the remark on `Composite`: you did not understand it >> `Composite` means that the class can indeed be composed of any number of mixins.

Comment: I thought about Visitor and I decided that it's a good solution. So I'm going to try this pattern and rewrite my code. This will demand a many functions for each class and this fact confusing me, I will need a function per operation in each mixin class, it's too big overhead.

Answer (score 2):

First thing that comes to mind is asking what you really want to achieve... but then again the second thought is that you can use the visitor pattern. Runtime type information will implicitly be used to determine at what point in the hierarchy is the final overrider of the accept method, but you will not explicitly use that information (your code will not show any `dynamic_cast`, `type_info`, constants...)

Then again, my first thought comes back... since you are asking about the appropriateness of the architecture, what is it that you really want to achieve? --without knowledge of the problem you will only find generic answers as this one.

Comment: I'm trying to describe. Imaging and rpg game and a lot of stuff in it. Each simple kind of stuff has a type, for example weapon, armor, garbage, light, potion, scroll, book, etc. Each type implemented as mix-in class. But many items in a game can have more than one type, for example, it can be a large axe that has a light and a hidden places for small items (weapon, light, container). Skin bag that can be weared on a belt, it can have a 1 armor point and behave like an armor and like a container. In different places of app I want to operate with composite objects like with simple ones.

Answer (score 1):

The usual object oriented way would be to have (pure) virtual functions in the base class that are called in `operate()` and that get overridden in the derived classes to execute code specific to that derived class.

Comment: If I do as you propose than I have all functions prototypes of each mixin class in my base. For now it's about 55 functions in 20 classes. I don't want to have so big Facade in my base class. And I think that base class must not know about children.

Comment: This is the only right way to do it in C++ unless you want to use templates. If object `P` has to handle object `Q` but really only has information about `Q` through a base class named `B`, then `B` has to define anything `P` needs to access in `Q` (since `P` knows nothing of `Q`'s declarations). That could be limited to the `operate()` function though.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you want to decide what to do based on more than one object's type. Virtual functions do this for one object (the one left of the `.` or `->`) only. Doing so for more than one object is called [*multiple dispatch*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) (for two objects it's also called [*double dispatch*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)), and in C++ there's no built-in feature to deal with this.

Look at double dispatch, especially as done in the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).